Digital Output circuit with optocouplers
I want to design a digital output circuit using optocoupler. My out low level voltage max is 0.99 V, out high level voltage min. is 2.4 V and the output current should be max. 100 mA. Moreover withstand voltage should be 50 V. My input voltage is independent, it can be 0-5 V. How can I design it by using optocoupler or anyway?
There is a 3.3 V source in secondary side and there is an unstable source in primary side and it is ripple between 3.3 V and 0 V.

What is the power source for the opto circuit output stage?  A standard opto has a bare transistor as the output device, and all that device can do is sink current from its collector to its emitter.  You can add an external transistor to boost the current capability to 100 mA, but that current comes from somewhere.  Where?  specifically, what is the value of the voltage that powers the secondary circuit?  Please update your question with this information.

Thank you I've just updated

Does the output side have to source 100 mA into a load (pull up to the 3.3 V source), sink 100 mA from a load (pull down to GND), or both?
